# Superscript placement when typesetting with "odd" subscripts

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

From time to time I typeset classical papers, trying to obtain (as close as possible) the original appearance of the document. I'm currently fiddling with a paper in German that uses the lowered quotation mark as a pseudo-subscript:
[image]

(Sorry, the image is a little blurry.)

I'm having trouble positioning the exponent correctly:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$ v{„}^2 = 1330w{„}^2 + 1831 $
\end{document}
```

I'll note that making the lowered quotation mark an actual subscript doesn't look right -- it ends up being much too low.

Comment: `v\rlap{„}^2`. Or \mathrlap from mathtools.

Comment: isn't the original more like `w_{„}^2` ?

Comment: Is that subscript supposed to be a double quote or a double prime?  I've seen primes more often than quotation marks in this position.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Using `\mathrlap` works great. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Making the „ into a subscript pushed it down too far, in my opinion.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's an excellent question. I made the assumption that it was the German lower double quote since the original paper is in German, but it might well be a double prime. Thank you for the observation.

Comment: @Derek try `w_{\prime\prime}` which would be bigger than a lowered low quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your pick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\subquoteA}{%
  \scriptscriptstyle
  \prime\mspace{-1mu}\prime
}
\newcommand{\subquoteB}{\textup{\raisebox{-0.5ex}{''}}}

\begin{document}

\[
v_{\prime\prime}^2 = 1330w_{\prime\prime}^2 + 1381
\]

\[
v_{\subquoteA}^2 = 1330w_{\subquoteA}^2 + 1381
\]

\[
v_{\subquoteB}^2 = 1330w_{\subquoteB}^2 + 1381
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As usual, nice nice.